# Pretty URL with yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I trying to enable pretty url in yii2 but it doesn't work as needed.

urlManager configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
     'showScriptName' => false,
     'baseUrl' => '/',
]

public function actionIndex($custom_param)
{
    print($custom_param);
}
```

`example.com/mycontroller?custom_param=value` works perfectly. But I need URLs such as `example.com/mycontroller/value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply this to`index` action of `mycontroller` and in case of `custom_param` is integer, add this to `rules` section of `urlManager`:

```
`urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        'mycontroller/<custom_param:\d+>' => 'mycontroller/index',
    ],
],
```

Otherwise you can modify pattern to fit your needs.

For example if `custom_param` is string, change `d+` to `w+`.

If you want to apply this rule to other controllers, you can do it like this:

`'<controller:(mycontroller|anothercontroller)>/<custom_param:\d+> => '<controller>/index'`,

Read more in official documentation:

- [Guide to url rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules)
- [Guide to parameterizing routes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#parameterizing-routes)
- [UrlManager $rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail)

Comment: What is if the custom param has a specific value? i,e `controller/action/1` to be `controller/action/` In other words removing the param value if it has specific value. It is very important in pagination and SEO

Answer (score 1):

In your web.php file below Components use this code:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ],
```

Create A .htaccess file in your web folder and paste it:

```
RewriteEngine on # If a directory or a file exists, use it directly RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # therwise forward it to index.phpRewriteRule . index.php
```